# hibernate query result to a predefined object?

Tags: java, hibernate

It is possible in hibernate to get a result of a query to a mapped db object.

Is it possible to create a non-persistent object and get the query result into this object?

for example

```
session.createSQLQuery(select a,b,c from table).list.addEntity(myclass.class)
```

if myclass is:

```
public class myclass{

private int a;

private int b;

private int c; 
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select a,b,c from table")
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(myclass.class))
    .list();
```

Comment: how can i do it if 'a' is a column with a foreign key to another table, and i want that table's records fetched into an object, but the object is also a non-persistent object?

Comment: @dan: I think you'll need to create a custom `ResultTransformer`.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, trying "select x as someValue ..." and i get exception telling no SOMEVALUE setter found, traced down discovered it really looks for setSOMEVALUE case sensitive :(

Answer (score 0):

No, Hibernate will only work with classes that are mapped ahead of time.